# Qt - Pop up a bubble when mouse is over QRect object

Tags: c++, qt

My `QRect` object is a fixed-sized containter of plain text, when there is too much text I would truncate the text and trail `...` at the end. For example, `Longlonglonglong` is truncated to `Longlong...`. But I want to display the full-length text in a bubble when mouse pointer is over the rect.

The bubble is like the `Go to Google Home`:
[image]

Is  this possible ?

Comment: `QRect` is a geometric type that describes a rectangle - it can't 'contain' anything.  What are you actually using?

Comment: @cmannett85 I'm using this: `void QPainter::drawText ( const QRectF & rectangle, int flags, const QString & text, QRectF * boundingRect = 0 )`. Maybe 'container' is not proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `QPainter` can't do that for you, the `drawText(..)` flags don't support it.  Thankfully, you can pre-elide the text for it ("eliding" is where you truncate with an elipsis) using `QFontMetrics`:

```
QFontMetrics fontM( QApplication::font() );
QRect r( 0, 0, 30, 10 );
QString text = "Longlonglonglong";
QString elidedText = fontM.elidedText( text, Qt::ElideRight, r.width() );

painter->drawText( r, Qt::AlignLeft, elidedText );
```

When you say "text in a bubble when mouse pointer is over", I presume you mean a tooltip - in which case implement it for the widget as normal and give the full text rather than the elided.